# how to change the image of imageview on changing configuration in android

Tags: android

as new to android and have a requirement that imageview src image change when changing the phone oreintation(portrait to landscape and vice versa) .set the image for imageview is ok for me but how can the above requirement can be achieve.is this thing possible in android.
Thanks .A little help will be very much appreciate.
here i am mention the two layout  which contain some imageview

1 the portrait mode of design

[image: portrait design of app]

2.the landscape mode of design 
[image: landscape design of app]
 if anything more require please ask me.
the app is design for the android version 2.3 and api level 10

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 2) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.landscapeimage);
    } else if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 1){
        imageView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.portraitimage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create Layout-land and from that you can copy paste your code from the layout folder , and change the imageview to whatever you like. now when the user change orientation it will go to the layout-land. hope that help you.

Comment: can you tell how you did it exactly ? ?
first you have to create folder called layout-land than create xml base on the other portrait layout and , change the image only. 
hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

write this in onStart()

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

if(width<height){
   //in portrait mode

}
else{
   //in landscape mode.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create new layout and put it to its designated folder such like:

```
- layout layout-800x400 
- layout-land 
- layout-land-800x400 
- layout-port
- layout-port-1232x800
```

etc.

in each folder are adjusted layout depends on what design would you want it to be like. Now, if its not working, you have to identify the dimension or resolution of your device and add it as your layout folder like sample above,coz maybe the device was unable to find the layout folder for it.

for more reference check this link 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html